# Paho MQTT AlarmPingSender wakelock stucked

Tags: android, mqtt, android-wake-lock

I am using Paho Android Service for my project (app name is **Sealer**). ([link](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/))

I've tested it about 22 hours and the result has brought me a strange result.

It seems that my app keeps awake the CPU a very long time (~10,5 h).

I've searched in the source code by wakelock tag and found that the wakelock tag belongs to the AlarmPingSender class. Has anybody met this problem ever ?

I **didn't** modify the Android Service source code, it's the original.

I've attached some screenshots (Hangouts and Viber just for comparison).

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh3b6.jpg)

**EDIT 1.**

There is a code snippet from my source code:

```
    mqttOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    mqttOptions.setCleanSession(false);
    // defaultKeepAlive is 240
    mqttOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(Constants.defaultKeepAlive);
```

**EDIT 2**

I think this is the relevant code from Android Service source code:

```
/*
 * This class sends PingReq packet to MQTT broker
 */
class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private WakeLock wakelock;
    private String wakeLockTag = MqttServiceConstants.PING_WAKELOCK
            + that.comms.getClient().getClientId();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // According to the docs, "Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as
        // long as the alarm receiver's onReceive() method is executing.
        // This guarantees that the phone will not sleep until you have
        // finished handling the broadcast.", but this class still get
        // a wake lock to wait for ping finished.
        int count = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALARM_COUNT, -1);
        Log.d(TAG, "Ping " + count + " times.");

        Log.d(TAG, "Check time :" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        IMqttToken token = comms.checkForActivity();

        // No ping has been sent.
        if (token == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Assign new callback to token to execute code after PingResq
        // arrives. Get another wakelock even receiver already has one,
        // release it until ping response returns.
        if (wakelock == null) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) service
                    .getSystemService(Service.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    wakeLockTag);
        }
        wakelock.acquire();
        token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Success. Release lock(" + wakeLockTag + "):"
                        + System.currentTimeMillis());
                //Release wakelock when it is done.
                if(wakelock != null && wakelock.isHeld()){
                    wakelock.release();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken,
                    Throwable exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failure. Release lock(" + wakeLockTag + "):"
                        + System.currentTimeMillis());
                //Release wakelock when it is done.
                if(wakelock != null && wakelock.isHeld()){
                    wakelock.release();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It seems (at least according to the screenshots) that the wakelock somehow is 'stucked', doesn't released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and created a bug report. Please have a look for further help: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480134

Comment: Thank you, this change has fixed this problem ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The ping sender will need to wake up to send a ping at what ever keep alive period is configured. The app needs to wake to send the packet that keeps the connection alive. I've not played with the Paho Android service but you should be able to change this by adding the relevant values to the MQTTConnectOptions object passed to the MQTTAndoridClient.connect() method.

EDIT:

e.g.

```
MQTTConnectOptions opts = new MQTTConnectOptions();
opts.setConnectionTimeout(240000);
client.connect(opts);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, but I don't understand you completely. What does _relevant values_ mean ?

Keep alive period now is 240 second.

Comment: I've updated the answer to help a bit. But 240 seconds is probably a pretty good default, I tend to use 300 (5mins) but that is just habit.

Comment: Yes, thats how my code looks like, I've updated my original post. But I don't understand how should this setting causes this 10 hour CPU awake ? It's just tell the service the keep alive period so it can send a ping packet every 240 second.